# How to make an RMI server multi-client program without registerting clients

Tags: java, rmi

I have a RMI server which a number of clients connect to. When a client registers a change, the server reacts and instructs all clients to make a change.

I have been looking into a number of hello world RMI examples, but none of them addresses how to persist a connection back to the client from the server.

What i would like to achieve is something along these lines:
Server is registered on the rmiregistry.
Client 1 connects to the server and calls a method on the server.
Client 2 connects to the server and calls a method on the server.
The server sends the change from client2 to client1.

How does one achieve this without registering every client as a server?

EDIT:
After looking at a couple of excellent ansvers (flatter flatter) i am running into the following exception
java.rmi.StubNotFoundException: Stub class not found: thegame.connectivity.GameClient_Stub; nested exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: thegame.connectivity.GameClient_Stub
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:292)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createProxy(Util.java:140)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:196)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:310)
    at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:237)
    at thegame.connectivity.GameClient.bind(GameClient.java:37)
    at thegame.connectivity.GameClient.run(GameClient.java:51)
    at thegame.connectivity.GameClient.main(GameClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: thegame.connectivity.GameClient_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.Util.createStub(Util.java:286)
    ... 7 more
```

On this class

```
public class GameClient extends Thread implements Remote, Client, ModelChangeListener<Client>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -394039736555035873L;
    protected Queue<GameModelEvent> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<GameModelEvent>(); 


    public GameClient(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GameClient client = new GameClient();
        client.run();
    }


    protected void bind(){
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase","file:bin/");
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            Client c = (Client)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
            Server stub = (Server) registry.lookup("Server");
            stub.registerClient(c);
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        bind();
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print(".");
            GameModelEvent event = queue.poll();
            while(event != null){

                System.out.println(event);


                event = queue.poll();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
...
```

It works well when i comment out the UnicatRemoteObject and just pass null as a parameter. So there is a connection and everything is running. But no stub...
Commenting out the codebase has no effect either. The codebase works fine on the server.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: this might help: http://java.sys-con.com/node/46979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients can not only talk to the server, they can also talk with each other directly.

Register clients on a client, building something like tree structure that starts from a small number of "master clients", and only these are registered with the server. They can cascade messages down to to other sub-clients, so potentially a very big number of clients could be supported having only few registered directly on the server.

Unfortunately, with this approach the client must be allowed to have a proper shutdown, so that they could distribute the duties about the sub-clients they currently have to other nodes, or return to the server. They cannot be simply killed as the whole tree branch will be severed. Maybe if the client feels there is no longer connection with the master, it should appeal to the server and obtain another.

See also [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html) on that can be done.

Also to not call `exportObject(Remote obj)` because using it requires to have a stub class (it returns an instance of the class, `RemoteStub`). Use `exportObject(Remote obj, int port)` that returns an interface. Covered also [here](http://www.stratos.me/2008/05/stub-class-not-found/).

Comment: How do you register the clients?

Comment: A client can invoke remote method on the server passing the self as parameter. The server can later pass this reference also to other clients so they could talk directly. You can pass RMI handles a easily as ordinary objects on the same jre.

Comment: Audrius: I Attempted to make a callback listener but i am getting a nasty exception. Any idea what is wrong? I updated the question with details

Comment: Be sure all classes are accessible for both server and client. You can always use rmic to produce that missing class. Stubs should generally not be required but maybe we are missing some other classes that are required to create generate them on the fly.

Comment: The server and client are taken from the same codebase at the moment. They are also using the same classpath. How can they have a class missing from one but not the other? It seems to be a generated class GameClient_stub.

Comment: Running RMIC on the client did squat

Comment: exportObject(Remote obj) returns a stub class (and not interface) so you need a stub if you use this method.

Answer (score 2):

When your clients first contact the RMI server, they can provide a listener of some kind that implements the `Remote` interface. The server can maintain a set of these `RemoteListener`s and, whenever clients should be notified of some event, it can invoke whatever `remoteAction(ActionEvent e)` you want to create. Without knowing more about your problem domain, it's hard to be specific.

Comment: Can you give me a hint along the lines of some api or examples?

Comment: Every client receives its specific Listener object. client1 calls a send message method, that the rmi server sends to the listener of client 2.

Comment: A good example with sources can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/rmi/callbak.htm#1023775

Comment: I tried creating a client but i am getting an exception that i can't quite figure out. Help?

Comment: Arvik's link describes in better detail what I was trying to get at. @Arvik, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to achieve using RMI-callback. Lots of details and the source code are available at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13211_01/wle/rmi/callbak.htm#1023775.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Part I)**

To do this with purely RMI the client will has to act as an RMI server for the purposes of the callback - there's simply no getting away from that, it's how the RMI protocol works.

If you don't want each client to behave in this way then you're going need to drop down a level in the network stack and implement your own socket protocol in place of RMI.  When the register message is received by the server it would need to hold onto the socket connection made by the client pushing data back to the client over that socket as need be.

**Answer Part II (Following the edits to the question))**

You need to have pregenerated a stub when you export the client when using [`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject%28java.rmi.Remote%29) as indicated by the following comment from the JDK source:

*Use UnicastServerRef constructor passing the boolean value true to indicate that only a generated stub class should be used.  A generated stub class must be used instead of a dynamic proxy because the return value of this method is RemoteStub which a dynamic proxy class cannot extend.*

Hence the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Well, either that or call [`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject%28java.rmi.Remote,%20int%29).

You also need to *bind* the stub to the registry using specifying a service name with the call [`Registry.bind(String, Remote)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/Registry.html#bind%28java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote%29).

This is in effect running the client as an RMI server - as I said in my answer 'Answer Part I', this is the only way this can work when using RMI - RMI there to make remote method invocations, nothing more.